# AutoMapper e ViewModel com campos iguais

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma *Viewmodel* (`UsuarioGrupoViewModel`) onde irei mostrar dados de usuário e de grupos na mesma View.

O problema é que tanto a entidade Usuário quanto a entidade Grupo tem o campo Nome, como trato isso?

Obs: estou usando `AutoMapper` e minhas *Viewmodels* ficam na camada de aplicação.

Comment: Consegue postar aqui o código da view model e da entidade para qual você está tentando mapear?

Comment: Olá Felipe, estou respondendo de uma máquina que não tem os fontes, mas preciso mostrar dados da tabela usuários e grupos, as duas tabelas tem o campo NOME, como eu poderia criar uma viewmodel com esses dois campos iguais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `AutoMapper` funciona para mapear uma única classe em uma outra única classe. Então, se na sua ViewModel você terá informações de um grupo e de um usuário, sugiro que crie uma classe que possua uma referência para cada uma delas. Algo que será instanciado assim:

```
var usuarioGrupo = new UsuarioGrupo 
{
    Usuario = usuario,
    Grupo = grupo
}
```

A partir daí, eu enxergo duas possibilidades:

1) Você vai ter sua classe `UsuarioGrupoViewModel` com referências para outras duas classes ViewModel: `UsuarioViewModel` e `GrupoViewModel`. Ou seja, para acessar o nome do grupo, você buscará em `usuarioGrupoViewModel.Grupo.Nome`.

2) Você também pode criar os campos NomeGrupo e NomeUsuario e configurar um `Profile` do `AutoMapper` para preencher estes campos, com algo assim:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UsuarioGrupo, UsuarioGrupoViewModel>()
  .ForMember(d => d.NomeGrupo, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Grupo.Nome))
  .ForMember(d => d.NomeUsuario, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Usuario.Nome))
  .ReverseMap();
```

Costumo utilizar as duas abordagens.

Comment: E como eu faço esse mapeamento? Na controller? No ViewModel? Gostaria de saber onde eu faço algo como Mapper.Create(...)

Comment: Você deve criar uma classe que herde de AutoMapper.Profile (ex.: UsuarioGrupoMapperProfile). Nela, em seu construtor, você faz o CreateMap, como no exemplo da resposta. Esta classe deve ser configurada (pode ser no Global.asax.cs, no Application_Start, para simplificar). Ali você faz o Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<UsuarioGrupoMapperProfile>(); });