# Como gravar informação(cpf) de um edit com máscara e um campo numérico

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

No banco tenho o campo CPF do tipo bigint. Na model ele é um long. Isso é o que foi pedido no requisito. Bem, na model mascarei para um DataType.Text para aceitar a máscara,  mas quando saio do campo(OnBlur) aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro, que não fui quem a colocou e não sei de onde ela vem:

> O campo CPF deve ser um número

Essa é a minha model, mas aceito sugestão

```
public class Funcionario

{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Nome do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings =false)]
    [Display(Name ="Nome")]
    public String nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Data de Nascimento do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "formato de data invalido")]
    public DateTime dataNascimento { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CPF do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "CPF")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text, ErrorMessage ="Formato inválido")]
    public long cpf { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome da Cidade")]
    public String NomeCidade { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cidade do funcionário é obrigatório", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Cidade")]
    public virtual int cidade { get; set; }
}
```

No meu cshtml, criei uma jquery para máscara e uma função js para tentar passar apenas o número, mas entendo que mesmo sem os sinais da máscara, o cpf continua sendo uma string e não um número. Abaixo as funções

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

    <script>
        $("#cpf").inputmask("mask", {
            "mask": "999.999.999-99"
        }, {
                reverse: true
            });
        $("#nascimento").inputmask("mask", {
            "mask": "99/99/9999"
        }, {
                reverse: true
            });


        function replaceCpf() {
            var campo = document.getElementById('cpf');
            var cpf = campo.value;
            campo.value = cpf.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
        }

    </script>
```

A pergunta é bem simples: Há alguma forma de eu criar um edittext com máscara e depois ao gravar, passar de texto para long e gravar?

Comment: Acredito que seria uma boa prática separar o modelo de banco do modelo de exibição. Se tivesse um campo por exemplo "CEP" no banco do tipo `int` mas quisesses na sua *View* transformá-lo em dois `inputs`, como faria? Por isso é melhor ter uma *model* para a *View* e outra que é seu modelo de dados

Comment: @RicardoPontual, me explica uma coisa. Eu tenho uma API e um MVC(View). Se eu manter a model da API como um long e no MVC eu faria um String(Model)? É isso?

Comment: Sim, e claro quando você for salvar informações vai precisar passar os dados de uma model para a outra, na *controller* por exemplo, mas isso te dá mais flexibilidade e não causa dependências entre o modelo e o que está na página. Todos aqueles atributos de *annotations*, como *requred* e *display* não precisam estar na sua model do modelo de dados, somente na model que usar na *view*

Comment: Você diz então para eu criar uma ViewModel. Vi isso agora com um colega e acho que esse é o caminho.

Comment: Exatamente, uma model para atender a View. Dai você pode definir a propriedade como `string`, formatar, deixar do jeito que atenda bem a sua View.

Comment: Eu criei uma ViewModel, mas no momento de passar o CPF está indo 0.0. Falta alguma coisa nessa conversão que não estou conseguindo fazer, uma função javascript e etc. Como eu passo da VM string para o meu serviço receber decimal(11,0)? Eu troquei de bigint para decimal, porque no requisito está numérico de 11 e só o decimal me permite um length do campo

Answer (score 0):

O Ideal seria criar um mapeador do ViewModel para o Model, onde deveria converter apartir da chamada da camada de serviço dentro do controller.

Uma sugestão é usa a biblioteca [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/)

Talvez essa resposta ajude com o uso do AutoMapper: [AutoMapper e ViewModel com campos iguais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109305/automapper-e-viewmodel-com-campos-iguais)

Comment: Eu tenho uma API que estava batendo com a model. Criei a VM e como fica a API, essa é a dúvida. O AutoMapper resolve isso?

Comment: Em realidade é apenas um campo, que na VM é string, mas a API deve pegar esse campo como decimal(11,0). Será necessário um AutoMapper mesmo?

Comment: tu pode converter a VM quando cair no controller, de cara é a forma mais facil de converter. Como ta o teu controller ?